# stretched textures

Tags: texturing, uv

Model is scaled and unwrapped correctly, I think so. 
But still there are some textures which are stretched
[[image]1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAaWY.jpg)

[[image]2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XSNK.jpg)

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure the UV map is connected? This looks like a checker texture with generated coordinates.

Comment: I think so. Yes, this is really a checker texture. Check out the new photos, maybe now you will understand the problem and help me. Thx

Comment: Create a seam on the outside of the rim and see if this changes anything. The yellow polygons shown in your UV map mean, that the island is stretched.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of your shader nodes please?

Answer (score 0):

Scale the rectangular part of the mesh along Y-axis in the UV-editor to about the size of the circular parts.

Comment: did not help((((

Comment: Have you marked the newly created loops as seams?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: My bad. It's simple, actually. Just scale the rectangular part of the mesh down on Y-axis in the UV-editor. No need for any additional loops.

Comment: i knew this trick* but here it wont help me